# What is this JSON variation?

Tags: json

I have got some data that seems to be JSON but with data types and string lengths.

```
Data=a2:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"user";s:7:"example";s:5:"email";s:19:"example@example.com";}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"user";s:8:"example2";s:5:"email";s:20:"example2@example.com";}}
```

Comment: I don't think that would be proper JSON even if you disregarded the `:[0-9]` portions of it.

Comment: Looks invalid. Is that whole thing supposed to be an object or a string?

Comment: @Renan It's certainly not. But it does look like someone took JSON and threw *several* extensions at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only connection it probably has to json is that it uses things like `{`, `:` etc.

This looks like a serialized string: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

Depending on what is going to happen with it, where it came from, etc you can find out what it  was / needs to be. It could be a simple object where your language's "serialize" function was called on, and then made into a literal string to  feed to some database

See for an example this php function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

What it could be is that you have an app in PHP that reads serialized data from a database, and another app (like java) is trying to (pre-?) fill this database with some object. now java doesn't know how to serialize for php, but it can have a copy/pasted piece of text by a developer in it. 
I'm not saying that it is exactly that, but as it kinda looks like php serialized code but the assignment doesn't, it might be some form of combination of the two. Impossible to say without more info.

Answer (score 1):

This is not JSON.  JSON has no *variations*.  This appears to be a serialized string.  This is pretty close to how PHP serializes, but the start should be `a:2` instead of `Data=a2`.  It could be serialized by some other language, though.  If you know the source language, it should provide some method for deserializing it into data structures of that language.

Comment: JSON has no officially sanctioned variations. Nothing's stopping anyone from taking JSON and creating another data format heavily based on it. I would call that a variation.